# Dual touch screen system - how to open application in another monitor?

Tags: xrandr, multi-monitor

So I have dual touch screen system and I have mirrored the display output be the same in both displays. But now when other touch screen is being used I would like to open this other application on the other monitor (the application will just draw something on the monitor).

I have done the mirroring by simply:

```
xrandr --output DP1 --mode 2560x1080 --output HDMI2 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as DP1
```

I have also tried utilizing the environment variable DISPLAY by:
`DISPLAY=:0.x /path/to/application`   <-- but I'm not really sure how this should work because `DISPLAY=:0.0` is the only possible option because `DISPLAY=:0.1` -> Couldn't connect to X server' and this will also show the output in both monitors..

If you have any suggestions on how to solve this OR if you have even better solution I would appreciate it a lot! But the essential thing here is that both monitors should display the same content except when other touch screen is being used I would like to open this magical blocking application!

Answer (score 0):

Placement of windows is dependant on Window Manager. Therefore, you should change configuration of your window manager and see how you can customize window placement.

Please note that you since you set screens to mirror, it will be probably impossible to make one of the screens show some different application, or at least kind of unnatural(since that would defeat the very purpose of the mirroring).